# How to query a table field that does not have a certain value

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables:

Table Name: Assets

```
AssetName  
----------  
Bread1  
Bread2  
Bread3
```

Table Name: Ingredients

```
AssetName    Ingredient  
----------   -----------  
Bread1       Flour  
Bread1       Water  
Bread1       Yeast  
Bread1       Salt  
Bread2       Flour  
Bread2       Water  
Bread2       Yeast  
Bread2       Salt  
Bread2       Sugar  
Bread3       Flour  
Bread3       Water  
Bread3       Yeast  
Bread3       Salt  
Bread3       Vanilla
```

I am trying to write a query that shows me the list of assets that do not have Vanilla and expect the answer to be:

```
AssetName  
----------  
Bread1  
Bread2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT AssetName FROM Ingredients WHERE Ingredient != 'Vanilla'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use not exists.

```
SELECT 
    AssetName
from 
    Assets 
where not exists
    (
        Select 
            AssetName 
        from 
            Ingredients 
        where 
            Ingredients.AssetName = Assets.AssetName 
            and Ingredient = 'Vanilla'
    )
```